# Cost of .NET basic objects and operators

Tags: .net, performance

I'm working on an application that has performance that is more sluggish than I'd like it to be.

I found this article on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852

But it's obviously not current, and I know they are constantly optimizing the CLR. Is there a good document like this for how different primitives perform for .net 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: The first step would be to use a profiler to actually identify the slow parts.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think about the performance of the CLR's basic data types too much unless you have a good reason to think the bottleneck is there. I suggest you get a good profiler and start by profiling your application to find out where the bottlenecks are, e.g. in which methods the most time is spent.